# Call Revert Exception on safeSdk for getOwners on Polygon only [intermittent]

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

Intermittent bug on polygon network that gives
"Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getOwners()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0),Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getOwners()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

This happened on either safeSdk.createTransaction, safeSdk.getTransactionHash or safeSdk.signTransaction and we are connecting with metamask.

My hypothesis is that it is RPC connection related but would love any insights.

Answer (score 1):

[Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) developer advocate here

This means during the transaction execution, one of the calls have failed and the whole transaction is reverted.

It can be an error with your Polygon server, the smart contract, or one of the internal contracts it calls. It is tough to say what causes the failure without looking into the code. You can use [trace API](https://docs.chainstack.com/operations/ethereum/debug-and-trace-apis#usage-examples) to investigate the root cause.

Since this is a `getOwners()` function, I guess it returns all owners of some sort of token. Does it handle Owners[] == null properly?

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered a similar problem. After changing the RPC in MetaMask, it works without any issues.

Comment: Which RPC did you use?

Comment: @Ismael Many RPC nodes are probably good for the job. I opted for https://rpc-mainnet.matic.quiknode.pro